# Select * into customtablename from tablename

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to insert data from one table to another. I am using Select * into command. However, my table name is going to be generated dynamically as shown below -

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50) 

SET @Name = 'DimCategory'+CAST(GetDate() as Varchar(50)) 

select * into @Name from DimCategory
```

This gives me error that

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near 'DimCategory'.
```

Even following statement doesn't work.

```
select * into 'DimCategory' + CAST(GetDate() as Varchar(50)) from DimCategory
```

Is it the case that the table name should be hard-coded when we use

```
SELECT * INTO NEWTABLE_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME.
```

Or am I missing out something here?

Comment: Tag the proper RDBMS... SQL-Server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you are using `Sql Server`.

Your code needs dynamic SQL as follow:

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50) 
SET @Name = 'DimCategory'+CAST(GetDate() as Varchar(50)) 
DECLARE @sql = nvarchar(400)
SET @sql = N'select * into ' + QUOTENAME(@Name) + ' from DimCategory'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Since SQL2012 is tagged I'd suggest to include `QUOTENAME(@Name)`.

Comment: Worked. Many Thanks :)